# Adding dropdown menu to navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Evening,

Learning on the job, currently doing a new website for my family business.

How can I make this drop down navigation menu work on desktop/mobile? I don’t want it too fancy, same design as the main navigation itself, I have fiddled around trying to make it work like the actual toggle so when users click ‘Services’ it would toggle down but it is not working as expected.

Ideally on hover it should display the drop down links for desktop, and mobile it should require a touch for it to display.

HTML

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div class="navigation-item">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="/assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="navigation-bar-menu">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services <i class="fa-thin fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

        <ul class="navigation-bar-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Managed Print Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Document Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Machine Finance Options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Machine Repair & Support</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Products <i class="fa-thin fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="navigation-bar-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Machines</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ricoh</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lexmark</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Konica Minolta</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kofax</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Papercut</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Filestar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="navigation-bar-toggle">
      <i class="fa-light fa-bars"></i>
      Menu
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #242424;
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.12) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.32) 0px 2px 16px 0px;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 10rem;
  display: block;
}

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.navigation-bar-dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navigation-bar-menu {
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 100%;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar-menu .active {
  background-color: #242424;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navigation-bar-menu li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navigation-bar-menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navigation-bar a:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.navigation-bar-menu :not(.active):hover {
  background-color: #242424;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
}


.navigation-bar-menu.open {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 /* NAVIGATION BAR */
 .navigation-bar-toggle {
   display: none;
  }
  
  .navigation-bar-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    justify-content: end;
    width: auto;
    gap: 1rem;
  }

  .navigation-bar-menu li {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}
```

JS

```
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const menuToggler = document.querySelector('.navigation-bar-toggle')
  const menu = document.querySelector('.navigation-bar-menu')

  menuToggler.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('open')
  })
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
https://jsfiddle.net/fc471p3e/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I did what I could to achieve what you wanted with minimal changes and added comments where necessary. Check it out once. Made changes in HTML markup, CSS and JS. Let me know in the comments if you want me to explain some changes or if there are things that needs some explanation. One thing, if you are adding a link that has dropdown, **don't forget to add classnames** as I did in your markup. I have also commented what classnames to add as well. You can go through it and feel free to leave a comment if something isn't clear.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const menuToggler = document.querySelector('.navigation-bar-toggle');
  const menu = document.querySelector('.navigation-bar-menu');

  menuToggler.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('open')
  })

  const linksWithChild = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-btn');

  for (let i = 0; i < linksWithChild.length; i++) {
    linksWithChild[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      /* Upon clicking, check if any "dropdown-btn" other than the current one contains .active class. 
      If so remove .active class from the button and the dropdown will be hidden due to our style definition */
      for (let j = 0; j < linksWithChild.length; j++) {
        // 'this' refers to current dropdown-btn
        if (linksWithChild[j].classList.contains('active') && linksWithChild[j] !== this) {
          linksWithChild[j].classList.remove('active');
        }
      }
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }

})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #242424;
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.12) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.32) 0px 2px 16px 0px;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 10rem;
  display: block;
}

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.navigation-bar-menu {
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar-menu li.active a {
  background-color: #242424;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navigation-bar-menu li {
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-bar-menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.has-child .navigation-bar-dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-bar-menu.open {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  /* navigation bar */
  .navigation-bar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .has-child:hover .navigation-bar-dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navigation-bar-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    justify-content: end;
    width: auto;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  .navigation-bar-menu li a {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .has-child .navigation-bar-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    border-left: 2px solid #a5a7a8;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  /* show dropdown if the dropdown button has .active class */
  .has-child>a.active+.navigation-bar-dropdown {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* disable click evetns on devices that support hover */

@media screen and (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  .has-child>a {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div class="navigation-item">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="/assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- add .navlink class to every top level <li> tag -->
    <!-- add .has-child class to every .navlink <li> tag that has dropdown -->
    <!-- add .dropdown-btn class to direct <a> tag of .has-child <li> tag -->
    <ul class="navigation-bar-menu">
      <li class="navlink active"><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navlink has-child">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Services <i class="fa-thin fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="navigation-bar-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Managed Print Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Document Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Machine Finance Options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Machine Repair & Support</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="navlink has-child">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Products <i class="fa-thin fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="navigation-bar-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Machines</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ricoh</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lexmark</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Konica Minolta</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kofax</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Papercut</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Filestar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navlink"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="navigation-bar-toggle">
            <i class="fa-light fa-bars"></i>
            Menu
          </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dorji, thank you for this, I can make sense of what you have done, I ended up making a fully functional :hover one after hours of trying. Not ideal due to usability etc so this seems like a great use.

One thing, I can't get the drop down to display it's dropdown links on mobile responsive sizes whilst clickink/hovering on desktop and clicking on phone? Otherwise it works perfect on desktop and displays on hover.

Comment: Great to hear! I couldn't quite get you about the question though, do you mean the dropdown is not working in mobile responsive sizes while trying from desktop like in the devtool? Let me know.

Comment: I think I got you. If you are not toggling the device toolbar on the dev tool to show the responsive options at the top, the CSS will detect it as a hover-able device since you can hover with your mouse even if you adjust the screen to that of the mobile device. However, if you toggle the device toolbar and select a mobile device from the options on top, you will be able to show the drop-downs upon click since it simulates mobile device now.

Comment: Ahh yes, it works on the device toolbar, but I uploaded your code to my host and nothing happens on my iPhone 13 when I click one of the dropdowns

Comment: Is it possible that this is causing it not to work?

Element.setCapture() is deprecated. Use Element.setPointerCapture() instead. For more help https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture

Comment: Let me know which browser you are using to open the website and also I don't know where I/You have used the `Element.setCapture()` method in the code so let me know where it is in the code if there is since I couldn't find it. By the way the dropdown-menu toggling seems to work right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246334/discussion-between-dorji-tshering-and-rimsky).

Comment: Yes, I have responded :)

Comment: Hi Rimsky, I have updated the JS code to close other already opened dropdowns on clicking the current button(updated inside `for` loop). As for the `Element.setCapture()`, it just an outdated warning message specific to Firefox when you simulate mobile device on its console so nothing really to so with the code so feel safe!

Comment: I managed to get the parent drop down link to keep it's colour when scrolling through the submenu. Having difficulties making a dropdown an active link as it messes up all the submenu links and applies the same styles?

https://jsfiddle.net/of2081kj/168/